# How can I reshape my data frame to be used with cor() in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, correlation

I am varily new to R and data wrangling. 
I would like to calculate a correlation matrix using the cor()-function and for that I have to reshape my data frame. It consists of 1500 different articles (StockCodes) of an online store, with a sale history of 365 days per article (Quantity per Date per StockCode).

I need to reshape it in the form that the Dates become the new row names and the StockCodes become the new column names.

Concider this short example:

```
my_df <- data.frame(Stockcode = c("A","A", "B","B", "C", "C"), Quantity = c(1,5,3,2,1,4), Date = c("2010-12-01","2010-12-02","2010-12-01","2010-12-02","2010-12-01","2010-12-02") )
```

looking like this:

```
  Stockcode Quantity       Date
1         A        1 2010-12-01
2         A        5 2010-12-02
3         B        3 2010-12-01
4         B        2 2010-12-02
5         C        1 2010-12-01
6         C        4 2010-12-02
```

And I want it to be transformed into:

```
df_reshaped <- data.frame(A = c(1,5), B = c(3,2), C = c(1,4), row.names = c("2010-12-01","2010-12-02"))
```

looking like this:

```
           A B C
2010-12-01 1 3 1
2010-12-02 5 2 4
```

I achieved this with a for-loop (and successfully calculated my correlation matrix), but the loop took "ages" to be executed (approx. 4 hours).

Is there a proper and faster way?

I would highly appreciate any help!

Comment: Try `reshape(my_df, idvar = "Date", timevar = "Stockcode", direction = "wide", new.row.names = unique(my_df$Date))[, -1]` or maybe `unstack(my_df[, 1:2], Quantity ~ Stockcode)`

Comment: Thank you! "unstack" works and is very fast - it alters the column names a little and drops the invoice date/replaces it with id. But for the correlation matrix this does not matter. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way using `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`:

```
my_df %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Stockcode, values_from = Quantity) %>% ## pivot columns in wide format
   column_to_rownames(var = "Date") ## convert Date column to row names

#           A B C
#2010-12-01 1 3 1
#2010-12-02 5 2 4
```

Comment: `pivot_wider` is `tidyr`, not `dplyr`

Comment: @camille updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! This indeed does what I need (also on my larger data frame) and is much faster than the loop :-)

Comment: Awesome. Please consider accepting my answer if it solved your problem..

Comment: Done. Thank you again for the fast answer!